# Not able to see STDERR Output with docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, stderr

I'm running a php docker image (php:5.6-apache) which has apache's error and access logs redirected to STDERR and STDOUT respectively using symbolic links.

When I run the docker image in the foreground or access the docker container logs, I can see the STDOUT output. But I don't see any errors (even when I generate php errors).

Any idea why that is and how I can fix it?

I'm running docker for Mac (but I don't think this makes any difference)

Thanks

```
access.log -> /dev/stdout
error.log -> /dev/stderr
other_vhosts_access.log -> /dev/stdout
```

**Edit / Solved:**
As @BMitch mentions and proves below, the STDERR redirection works fine. 
The problem was with PHP configuration. If I logged an error with `error_log()`, it would get output to the log. But if I had a php error, like calling an undefined function, the error would never appear in the log. This seems a little inconsistent. In any case, ...

I had to create a `php.ini` file in `/usr/local/etc/php/` and add these two parameters:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

and then restart the docker container. This caused all PHP errors to be logged and output to STDERR. See @German's answer for an example.

Comment: Do you mount any volumes?

Comment: @BMitch, yes, but only /var/www

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce your situation. If the below doesn't help, please provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your error.

Basic Dockerfile:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM php:5.6-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

The only php is this file to generate an error:

```
$ cat error.php 
<?
error_log("Hello error log.")
?>
```

Build and run it:

```
$ docker build -t test-php .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/2 : FROM php:5.6-apache
 ---> f16436448ebd
Step 2/2 : COPY . /var/www/html/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cfe66485e2cc
Successfully built cfe66485e2cc
Successfully tagged test-php:latest

$ docker run -p 8080:80 -d --name test-php test-php
7f9a1836a8157963966b583579dff94c6413292547b84d22957add77ad2d8e14
```

Curl is empty as expected, but calling it generates an error in the logs:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/error.php
```

Show stdout logs, redirecting error to /dev/null:

```
$ docker logs test-php 2>/dev/null
172.17.0.1 - - [31/May/2017:00:06:37 +0000] "GET /error.php HTTP/1.1" 200 174 "-" "curl/7.38.0"
```

Show stderr logs, redirecting stdout to /dev/null

```
$ docker logs test-php >/dev/null
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed May 31 00:06:25.064546 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) PHP/5.6.30 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 31 00:06:25.064584 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed May 31 00:06:37.833470 2017] [:error] [pid 17] [client 172.17.0.1:50040] Hello error log.
```

Note the last line of the error output.

Comment: Yes, if you call `error_log()` directly, it seems to work. But if you call `error_pug()` (which doesn't exist of course), the log does not show any errors. You only get an error in the browser.

Comment: I was fighting with this this morning but ran out of time. I believe the php.ini needs to be updated but I couldn't get my changes to apply (probably writing the wrong file for the 5.6 build). This question goes into more detail on the php side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: This wasn't working as expected for me, turned out everything was logged as stderr. To inspect the raw log data (assuming default json-file logs driver) `less <$(docker inspect -f '{{.LogPath}}' CONTAINER)`

Comment: To disable an output, redirect it to ```&-```. This is the bash way to turn the descriptor off.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the php errors in the apache2 log you have to activate them. For this you have to write to the `php.ini` file into the folder `/usr/local/etc/php`.

I wrote an example in a repository so that the example can be seen.

https://github.com/nitzap/stackoverflow-docker-php-error-log

If you want to see the stdout and stderr logs, you can do it with the following command, outside of your containers:

```
docker logs <name_container>
```

Now if you want to remain attached in the log you can add the -f option as in the tail command.

```
docker logs <name_container> -f
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was missing this magic setting ("no" by default):

```
#/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
catch_workers_output = yes
```

Found it here [Symfony logs to stdout inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499825/symfony-logs-to-stdout-inside-docker-container)