# docker does not catch php-fpm outputs with symfony and monolog

Tags: php, symfony, docker

I am using the image `richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest` (1.5.2) and I started a container based on this image and executed `/bin/bash` inside.

There I :

- have installed composer
- created a new symfony4 project using `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project`
- have edited `my-project/config/packages/dev/monolog.yaml` to set :

  ```
  monolog:
      handlers:
          main:                   
              type: stream  
              path: 'php://stderr' 
              level: debug        
              channels: ["!event"]
  ```
- got the IP of my docker image using `docker inspect`
- and dump my container logs using `docker logs -f <my container>`

When I load `http://<my container ip>/my-project/public`, I don't see the symfony debug logs in my container logs output.

*Note : I see the nginx logs.*

Comment: _When I load `http://<my container ip>/my-project/public`, I don't see the symfony debug logs in my container logs output._ Why do you expect logs to be added? It looks like you're trying to see files in`public`, and files are probably served by your server, without Symfony.

Comment: @A.L : I don't understand your comment. When you have just done a new SF install, you have a demo route served on `/` and when you access it, you have debug logs output about which SF route is matched and so on ...
Note : it is a SF4 install so the `public` folder has an `index.php` file and not only the assets.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that `public` is different on Symfony4. Could you please share the commands you use to launch the container? I would like to try by myself.

Comment: I am using a simple docker run command. Something like this : `docker run -d --name testfpm richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest` command. Then I do the steps described in my ticket inside the container ``docker exec -it testfpm -- /bin/bash`

Comment: How did you have the idea to use `path: 'php://stderr'`? Could you please share a link that explain this usage? Maybe something is missing in this configuration.

Comment: I followed this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499825/symfony-logs-to-stdout-inside-docker-container and a bunch of other github issues and other SO questions.

Comment: Did you configured the supervisor log level too?

Comment: No I did not change the image settings for this tool. I attached mysql to the container, stopped fpm in the supervisor and run the same command in the console and I see the logs to the standard or error output. However supervisor does not seem to catch it and redirect it to its own output in order form them to be visible by docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my coworker found the solution and the docker image maintainer implemented it :

https://gitlab.com/ric_harvey/nginx-php-fpm/commit/51bbf4e04f61873dfeae69e943fcdf0a900f2589#8ad4b94617a62f898119a66a878f8035b8605d13

As php-fpm is run in nodaemonized mode, you need to set the `--force-stderr` flag which "Force output to stderr in nodaemonize even if stderr is not a TTY."

https://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=8&topic=php-fpm