# Monolog vs workers vs supervisord

Tags: symfony, docker, supervisord, monolog, runit

I can't get logs from the Symfony workers in my supervisord/runit log/stdout when starting my Docker container. Yes, I tried with supervisord and runit, but still does not work. If I have some exception in code I can see it regularly in stdout, but only that.

I'm afraid that something is with my Monolog configuration because if I add regular `echo` in my code I can see the output.

Monolog file is very simple:

```
handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
        channels: ["!event"]
    console:
        type: console
        process_psr_3_messages: false
        channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
```

I tried with `path: 'php://stdout'` or `path: 'php://stderr'` with/out changes in the php.ini files like: `display_errors = On`, `error_log = /proc/self/fd/2`, `catch_workers_output = yes`, but obeviously does not work. I can't find right combination.

Symfony workers are long-life process and I need some init processor to start it like supervisord or runit.

For runit, I tried some trick from this: https://git.nixaid.com/arno/show-runit, but as I mentioned above, regular `echo` works, and PSR Symfony logs not.

For both supervisord and runit, tried this: [Symfony logs to stdout inside Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38499825/symfony-logs-to-stdout-inside-docker-container), but same - does not work.

Any hint?

Comment: Usually you don't need supervisord or something similar to run a long-lived process in a Docker container; just run it directly, in the foreground, as the main container process, and its stdout/stderr will be the container's output.  Is there a technical reason you need supervisord anyways?  Can you include your image's `Dockerfile` in the question?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have multiple process/services. Dockerfile is not any special. Based on Alpine and some commands for install PHP

Comment: As I mention in question that I'm afraid is something with Monolog. Yes, there was a problem. With right configuration now I have logs

Comment: Great, maybe you can provide your solution?